# Inserting a new row after subtracting values from other rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to below in SQL Server:

```
ID Value
A   5
B   1
C   2
D   3
```

I need to insert a new row with ID 'E' whose value is A.Value-D.Value i.e.(5-3=2)
Output.

```
ID Value
A   5
B   1
C   2
D   3
E   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the values using `max` and `insert` the row. This assumes there can only be one value in the table for `A` and `C`.

```
insert into tablename (id,value)
select 'E',
max(case when id='A' then value end) - max(case when id='C' then value end) 
from tablename
```